# Detect swipe direction with SwipeView

Tags: javascript, swipeview

I'm use the great SwipeView library from cubiq.org.

The fact it uses endless optimized scrolling is great but I can't seem to find how to cleanly detect the swipe direction. I need this to update the shown data accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself and it's obviously really easy.

You can get direction from the directionX property on from the created SwipeView object.

```
swipeView.directionX
```

This will be 1 for a swipe to the right and -1 for left.