# Determining (Intentional) Swipe Direction

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to determine the direction a user swipes across the screen with a mobile device. I see everyone doing the tradition "start position - distance" or vice versa. Though I'd like to know the intentional direction; ie. the user changes direction part way through. The only proper implementations I've found are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930896/detect-swipe-direction-with-swipeview) & [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/).

Swipe view is nice, but it's a bit clunky and cubiq wants you sto use his pages system. The other demo is good too, but form what I can tell it just uses a barrage of if else's to determine direction. So does anyone know of a creative way this could be done that's lightweight?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about actual "swipes", meaning ones that would be recognized by a swipeGestureRecognizer? Do you need actual direction, like a vector, or do you just want left, right, up, down? A little more context would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable that holds the value of the pointer's last position. You need a second variable that hold the direction of the swipe. On mousemove, evaluate the direction from the new position and the old one, change the value in the swipe direction variable and then store the new position.

Comment: This is way it's usually done, but if the user drags across half the screen moving left, then they need to move the same distance and then some in the opposite direction in order for it to register right. I want it to be like throwing something.

Comment: The direction should get reevaluated every time the mouse moves, which it will if you follow my description. This way they can move 100px to the left, then 2px to the right (now being at -98px from the starting point), and the direction stored will be right.